# Confused with SVN

Tags: svn

I'm new with SVN, and I was given a branch that I have connected to with http://versionsapp.com/

However, I'm confused on how to get the files locally. Do I need to export them or checkout? I want to make a change to a file then update it in the svn repository.

Can someone give a good explanation on which one it is? If someone else updates a file, how do I get that file in my local copy thats on my machine?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: http://artis.imag.fr/~Xavier.Decoret/resources/svn/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to checkout the branch. If someone else makes a change, you'll have to update your working copy. Read http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.tour: it presents basic usage of SVN.

Answer (score 2):

Check out means create your own working directory where you can edit, commit your own changes, and receive changes committed by others.

To update with the freshest commits, do `svn update` in the working directory.  It will tell you which files have changed.  You need to do this periodically even if you are the only one who committed changes (perhaps after every commit).

The `export` feature is for creating a dump of the current tree with all the version-control stuff stripped out.

Comment: As a best practice kind of thing, you'll always want to do a `svn update` before you do your build to test your changes for `svn commit`.  When you update before you do your final test build you're much less likely to break the build and it keeps everyone else happy =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `checkout` the files , If you `export` you will not be able to sync your local copy with copy in SVN.
To get updated file use `update` option on local file. Alos you can use `commit` to add your changes to SVN.